# Real time streaming in a firebase database

Tags: c#, winforms, firebase-realtime-database

Im implementing a function which is to get the data in a specific child in my firebase database whenever something is added but I am getting an error 
"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties..."

Is there a way to fix this error? Thanks in advance

```
var observable = firebase
          .Child("Sold/Item")
          .AsObservable<SoldProductsData>()
          .Subscribe(d => MessageBox.Show(d.Key));
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what ambiguous overloads there are. Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe<T> (System.IObservable<T>, System.Action<T>)' and System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe<T>(System.IObservable<T>, System.Action<T>)'

Comment: That sounds like you have two versions of the same library included in your project.  A dependency might be including the second version.

Comment: @Amy yes I do have two version of it. FireSharp and FirebaseDatabase.net. Is there a way around it without removing the other one?

Comment: @Amy I tried removing the other version but I still have error it says "Cannot convert lambda expression tp type 'IOberserver<FirebaseEvent<SoldProductsData>>' because it is not a delegate type"